# How to write a jvm.config file for git-code-format-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, java-17

I want to configure my multi-modular maven project with git-code-format-maven-plugin.

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/Cosium/git-code-format-maven-plugin)
I have added the plugin in my pom.xml, as I am on JDK 17, I need to specify the jvm.config file too, but i don't have an idea how to do the same.

[jvm.config file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxrPQ.png)
[Location of jvm.config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roEhR.png)

How to pass the configurations correctly in the jvm.config file as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Cosium/git-code-format-maven-plugin#jdk-16-peculiarities)

Comment: What is the question? What you did? What is the problem, errors? Please don't attache image in questions.

Comment: I don't understand the consquence between JDK 17 and the need for `jvm.config`?

Comment: @khmarbaise  https://github.com/Cosium/git-code-format-maven-plugin#jdk-16-peculiarities they have pointed out the JDK 16+ peculiarities

Comment: Those configuration should be done in your maven-compiler-plugin configuration setup... Example repo https://github.com/khmarbaise/jdk21 more explanation of the details https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2023/06/2023-06-24-how-to-use-jdk21-preview-features-incubator/